# Opening applications in a different desktop from a command line

Tags: scripting, kde, workspaces

Is there a bash command which can open a particular application in a different desktop (virtual desktops) in KDE Plasma 5.8.7?

I'm trying to make a script file which when I run will make my entire workspace ready with different applications in different desktops.